# Need Tips for Algorithm

Tags: java, android, algorithm, random

i am wondering if you could help me in my project. I would to ask your opinion of what algorithm is best to used in generating random numbers that ranges from 1 to 9.. Its a game like "Sphere Break" a famous mini game of FFx-2.

Please refer to the picture for [image: example]

Need Opinions Please!! Need Help Badly.

My problem is that i want a certain algorithm to generate random numbers from 1 - 9 like in the picture every gameplay = another set of random coins...

P.S. i am developing an android game using unity !! thx for the response

Comment: `int getRandomNumber() { return 4; // Chosen by fair dice roll, guaranteed to be random}`

Comment: @user3580294 [`// Chosen by fair dice roll. Guaranteed to be random`](http://xkcd.com/221/)

Answer (score 3):

create a `List<Integer>` to hold 1-9 number and use `Collections.shuffle()` and render them